# AngularJS directive not using own scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am struggling with a problem with AngularJS directives.

I tried to copy all relevant code to a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/roger21/07mje0uw/1/  but noticed it only works in Chrome.

The directive has an isolated scope defined like this:

```
    this.scope = {
        values: "=",
        min: "@",
        max: "@",
        step: "@"
    };
```

The controller scope contains the value it binds to:

```
$scope.response = [
{
    "Day": "Monday",
    "Times":
    [
        { "Time": "06:00:00", "Temperature": 16.5 },
        { "Time": "08:00:00", "Temperature": 21.0 },
        { "Time": "18:00:00", "Temperature": 21.0 },
        { "Time": "22:00:00", "Temperature": 16.5 }
    ]
},
{
    "Day": "Tuesday",
    "Times":
    [
        { "Time": "06:00:00", "Temperature": 16.5 },
        { "Time": "08:00:00", "Temperature": 21.0 },
        { "Time": "18:00:00", "Temperature": 21.0 },
        { "Time": "22:00:00", "Temperature": 16.5 }
    ]
}];
```

The directive is then created like this:

```
 <div data-slider data-values="response[0].Times" data-min="0" data-max="1440" data-step="5"></div>
```

When you move the slider it updates the `values` property in the directive, and then it updates the object in the controller, as expected.

But now I add a second instance of the directive:

```
 <div data-slider data-values="response[0].Times" data-min="0" data-max="1440" data-step="5"></div>
 <div data-slider data-values="response[1].Times" data-min="0" data-max="1440" data-step="5"></div>
```

Now when I move the first slider is actually is bound to the values of `response[1].Times`, and it updates the values for that object!

I must be something missing with isolating the scopes here?

Comment: It appears the response array has its own shared scope. Can you break the array apart separately with their own scope?

Comment: Good call! But I tried that: http://jsfiddle.net/07mje0uw/2/ It seems like the 1st directive takes the `day2` binding!

Comment: I believe you can create two directives. Each directive containing scope.$apply(response[x]). Alternatively, you can also keep one directive but passing the response array into the 'attrs' property instead.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I thought the '=' in the scope for the directive means it would take the value it is given in and use it in it's own scope, that's the whole point of a directive right? Why would I have to separate the scopes outside the directives?